# What's wrong with my command? (might be me or a bug)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have this simple setup to show what the problem is:
[image: This is the setup]

this command block checks for a quartz block above it:
[image]

this one checks if the left command block's previous output is true:
[image]

But then when I remove the quartz block the right command block keeps emitting a signal.[image]

Can't tell if it's my fault because I really can't find my mistake.

Comment: I've forgotten quite a bit when it comes to Redstone mechanics but... Don't comparators stay on unless reset?

Comment: the command blocks on the far left and the far right put down a redstone block and destroy it afterwards which means the command blocks are getting updated constantly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are testing for a command block with a data value of 1.

A command block's data value does not store its success count, it instead stores whether the command block has been previously been activated with its current command in it. Its success count is instead stored in its NBT data, as it is a tile entity.

What you probably actually want to be testing for is a command block with `SuccessCount` of 1:

```
/testforblock ~ ~ ~1 command_block -1 {SuccessCount:1}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you :) If you don't mind, could you explain why it should be that way?

Comment: Aw... You've beaten me to it :P

Answer (score 1):

The reason your contraption is not working (middle-right is still outputting) is because the `/testfor` command is true, hence:

A command block will give itself a data value of 1 if it run a command. It does not indicate whether it is a success or not, only the fact that the command block has previously run a command.

The comparison of whether the result was a success or not are for comparators.

Comment: I see, I thought the 1 meant it was outputting a signal :p Thank you